# When outputing Chinese character, cout cause additional whitespace, but printf does not, why?l

Tags: c++, windows

After I upgrade my windows 10 to the Creator update, whenever I output some Chinese character using `cout`, I get an additional whitespace after each character. For example, if I write `cout << "123中文" <<endl;`, I get "123中 文 ". However, if I use `printf`, everything works fine, and I get "123中文".

I suspect this is a bug of the new console because a friend of mine has the same problem. And if I switch to the old console, everything works fine again.

If I redirect the output to a file or pipeline the output to another program, I found the output of cout and printf is identical. Now my question is how the console can distinguish `cout` from `printf`, and show me the different result?

**Edit:**

Now I'm adding more details.

The code I'm testing on is very simple.

`cout` test:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cout << "123中文" <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`printf` test:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("123中文\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Both source file is saved using code page 936 (GB2312) and compiled using Visual Studio 2017 Community. My Visual Studio and windows are both in Chinese.

The active code page of the console is 936.

I also wrote a simple program to see what my program exactly output:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cout << hex;
    while (cin)
    {
            cout << cin.get() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it to hexecho.exe

then in cmd, both `printftest | hexecho` and `couttest | hexecho` gave me the same output:

```
31
32
33
d6
d0
ce
c4
a
ffffffff
```

But couttest and printftest do show different result in my console.

I also tried PowerShell, PowerShell also has this problem.

Comment: That's going to be a tricky question to answer. The console doesn't know about C++, so it doesn't know whether you used `cout` or `printf.` Both are provided by your Standard Library implementation (Probably MSVC, but which version?).  This library will make different OS calls, in order to produce a different result.

Comment: Consider adding the tag `windows` since this is a Windows specific problem. Unicode is totally broken on Windows console, I wouldn't bother with trying to fix this.

Comment: The console has been getting hacked pretty hard in Win10 to support the Linux subsystem, anything is possible.  I find the details of the question rather questionable, cout just chatters to stdout, like printf does.  I suspect it has more to do with the exact glyphs, the console does support codepoints in the upper bit planes but they require two character cells for storage.  Fits the complaint, nothing much else does.  Decent repro code and exact details on the source file and console output page encoding are essential.

Comment: @HansPassant I have added more details, which I think are enough to reproduce this problem.

Comment: This has been fixed. There's no way to check the reason now.